# Using AWS crypto to create unique IDs

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-ios

I am using the aws-ios-sdk and need to create unique IDs for some of my data both in the ios app (objective-c) and in my aws lambda code.  Is there a way to use crypto/encryption sdk to make a unique ID that is say 16 alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Why not use use a UUID?

Comment: Reading about that now.